# how to open a website in google search results using python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I want to use python, selenium,  to search a specific keyword in google (done) and then open the websites of the results one by one (this is the problem)

my code is in the following:

```
for i in range (1,4):
    webdriver.get('https://www.google.com/')
    search = webdriver.find_element_by_name('q')
    search.send_keys(string)
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) 
    sleep(5)
    print("step1")
    check='/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div[10]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[%d]/div/div/div[1]/a[1]/h3/span' %(i) 
    webdriver.find_element_by_xpath(check).click()
    sleep(10) 
    print("hi")
```

The code works well for opening and searching the keyword (string is defined), but when I want to open the results by their xpath one by one, it fails. The error happens for the line "webdriver.find_element_by_xpath(check).click()"

That would be nice of you if you can help me.

Comment: And what is your error message?